Handlebars chart In Apache Superset is treating JSON as a string
I have data in a mysql database where I have structured it so that the first column is an id and the second column contains and array where each item in that array has an id and a status. In the sql lab in apache superset it shows that the array is infact an array and treats it as json. However, when I bring the data into a handlebars chart it treats it as a string and I cannot access the elements. How can I make it so that my data can be processed in handlebars?
Example of issue:
children.[0] shows up as "[" instead of status: "complete" because the data shows "[{"status": "complete"}] instead of being parsed as json
I have tried a ton of different commands in the sql lab to extract the data as json, however the issue seems to be stemming from how handlebars interacts with or handles the data when its being processed through superset. handlebars is supposed to be used with json, which is why I was very confused when it treated it as a string.
